# Simple question regarding probability mass function

Tags: probability

X is the number of sixes obtained when a fair dice is thrown 4 times.
I just have to write down what the distribution of X is and give the probability mass function.

So I have simply written down:

$X$~$Bin(4, \frac 16)$

However I never understand what I have to do when giving the probability mass function? Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 0):

Each distribution has its probability mass function (for discrete random variables) or probability density function (for continuous random variables).

Effectively, the distribution for your random variable is a binomial one with parameters $n=4$ and $p=\frac{1}{6}$. The probability mass function for the binomial distribution is

$\Pr(x=k) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Inserting your numbers in it, it turns into

$\Pr(x=k) = {4 \choose k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{4-k}$